# recursively split list into sub lists based on first element length

Tags: python, list, recursion, multidimensional-array, split

I am breaking my head around this small issue which I am sure can (and should) be solved recursively.

```
# split list in sublists based on length of first element. 
list = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
       #*          #*

# *number of elements of the sublist
```

It is better shown than explained, the above should result to:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

The lists I am processing always respect this logic, the first element is always the length of the following n elements.

EDIT:

Based on some of the suggestions, I simply added a yield to get it done lazily.

```
def split(ls):
    """
    func that given a list extracts sub lists with the length indicated by the first element
    [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4] => [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
    """
    res = []
    while ls:
        dim = ls[0]
        yield ls[1:dim + 1]
        ls = ls[dim + 1:]

    return res

>>> list(split([2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?? You have to show some kind of effort

Comment: This is highly susceptible to errors. The values that determine the length of the sub-lists have to be exactly right. What you are asking only works for very specific kinds of lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple slicing will do:

```
>>> a = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c = []
>>> while len(a) :
...     b = a[0]
...     c.append( a[1:b+1] )
...     a = a[b+1:]
... 
>>> c
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Instead of `while len(a)` we can use `while a`. Don't which one of the both is considered pythonic. So I commented. ;) Very cool answer btw.

Comment: I think it could be problematic this consumes `a`.  I've edited @GiftZwergrapper's answer to keep everything in the function scope and be more readable. His implementation may be the most usable.

Comment: @MiesvanderLippe Gift's answer uses `pop` method which mutates the list in place after calling `split_list`, `numbers` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, there he called recursive call on slice of `list_` so `numbers` won't lose any more elements. I posted an answer without consuming or changing the original list take look and any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I need to get my eyes checked ;) I was wondering exactly that.@Ch3steR I've edited my own answer instead, solving that problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to achieve what you want:

```py
numbers = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]

result = []
def split_list(list_):
    first = list_.pop(0)
    result.append(list_[:first])
    if len(list_[first:]) > 0:
        split_list(list_[first:])

split_list(numbers)

print(result)
```

Comment: The `list.pop(k)` first removes and returns the element at k, and then moves all the elements beyond k one position up. This would be **very** slow for any reasonable size of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) here.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> lst = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> def chunks(lst):
...     t=iter(lst)
...     c=next(t,None)
...     while c:
...             yield list(islice(t,None,c))
...             c=next(t,None)
...
>>> list(chunks(lst))
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: this solution is very beautiful! I ended up using this!

Answer (score -2):

I've edited my answer as inspired by someone else's in this thread. This doesn't consume the original array and uses recursion instead of looping.

```
numbers = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3,1,1,1,1]

def do_take(numbers: []):
    result = []
    to_take = numbers[0]
    result.append(numbers[1:to_take + 1])
    if len(numbers) > to_take:
        result.append(do_take(numbers[to_take + 1:]))
    return result

print(do_take(numbers))
print(numbers)
```

Results in the following output:

```
# python /tmp/breakup.py
[[1, 2, 3], [[1, 2, 3, 4], [[1, 1, 1], [[]]]]]
[3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```